# Express get raw HTTP request / response

Tags: node.js, http, express

How can i get raw HTTP message from req and res objects in Express?
I want to parse my request in http message like:

```
GET /someUrl HTTP/1.1
Host: my.site.com
```

I want to parse my final response in something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
SomeHeader: SomeValue
Hello world!
```

Comment: You can set express to use body-parser with raw mode

Comment: bodyParser.raw() is for binary data and representation http message body as Buffer, right?